# How do I determine programmatically what values to add to the proj4js constructor for a CRS or SRS such that I can iteratively render proper overlays

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, leaflet, proj

I think this is primarily a GIS based question as far as for example:

```
var crs = L.CRS.proj4js('EPSG:2154',
                    '+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
                    transformation);
```

So if I read in a wms tile layer through the leaflet api to create an overlay on a wfs base map how do I decide how to adjust those lat/lon values? And what is ellps, towgs, and units?

Comment: ellps is ellipsoid, units=m are meters; towgs84 is conversion into wgs84 datum http://proj.maptools.org/gen_parms.html

Comment: Ok, do you know how to determine what I should set those values to render a wms overlay on a wfs base map?

Comment: you can look then up at http://spatialreference.org